# How to check data in non-blocking sockets client

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, client

Client does:

```
connect()
select()
getsockopt()
write()
```

Everything is fine until this moment. But then server requires few seconds to send the status back and I want to receive it without any blocks on waiting. So how should I check that response from server is available? Should it be

- another `connect()` and then `recv()`
- or just `recv(sockfd, buffer, LINE_LENGTH-1, MSG_DONTWAIT);`
- or `select()` and then `recv()`

I can't find a clear example or good explanation of how it should look on
the client's side.

Comment: It can be helpful to build the components of a simple sockets based server & client in parallel, where, for example, when both launched, can be used to send messages back and forth.  In this way, you can use debugging on your code to see where the blocks are occurring.  Do you have a working server?  Have you run it in parallel with your new client to send simple messages back and forth.  You can test your server by using ***[TeraTerm](http://ttssh2.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en)*** ( or any terminal emulator that will allow you to do a tcp/ip connection.)

Comment: what kind of sockets are you using TCP or connected UDP sockets ?
Are the sockets in non blocking mode (O_NONBLOCK) ?
You dont need another connect as lon as you are communicating through the same socket

Comment: I built both apps by myself and yes I run them with all debugs in parallel on my host or via network it doesn't matter. Non-blocking TCP sockets used ( I thought thats obvious because term non-blocking used only for connection sockets). Things became complicated when I want to get response from the  server in non-blocking manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> another connect() and then recv()

Of course not. That would create another connection and you would be starting all over again.

> or just recv(sockfd, buffer, LINE_LENGTH-1, MSG_DONTWAIT);

That will work if the data has already arrived, otherwise it will return -1/EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK.

> or select() and then recv()

That will work. But so will a blocking-mode read with the same timeout value as you would use in the select, set as a read timeout.

Your question doesn't really make sense. You have to block until the data arrives, in either `select()` or a blocking `recv()`.

Comment: It does make sense. Maybe I just explain it wrong. I have a client which sends tasks to multiple servers and checks the return value. Task execution takes some time. So on client side I don't want to wait few seconds or even minutes when task will be ready. I just want to continue in the loop sending tasks to the other servers without any blocking by the server which is still busy. But I want to receive the status from the server when the task will be complete. So if I understand you well -  I should just call 
`recv(sockfd, buffer, LINE_LENGTH-1, MSG_DONTWAIT);` then continue with task send.

Comment: and from time to time call `recv(sockfd, buffer, LINE_LENGTH-1, MSG_DONTWAIT);` and keep socket open till I get the task status from the server. Am I right? )

Comment: You didn't mention multiple sockets. In that case you should certainly use `select(),` so you can wait for all the sockets at the same time. Then for every socket that comes up readable, call `recv()`: it won't block.

Comment: If I don't want to wait anywhere why should I use select() on client? Now I think `recv(sockfd, buffer, LINE_LENGTH-1, MSG_DONTWAIT);` is better solution.

Comment: What are you going do instead? Smoke the CPU? This is exactly what `select()` is *for.*

Comment: what are you talking about? what smoke? `select(); recv(MSG_DONTWAIT);` works fine btw.

Comment: Exacfly as I said. 'Smoke the CPU' is joking way of describing a spin loop that does nothing except waste CPU cycles. Blocking on some event is infinitely to be preferred.